# Remove the border where two division intersect

Tags: html, css

I am attaching two division's border and remove the border where two division intersect but its not remove. I have tried this code.

```
<div style="border:solid 1px #CCC; 
margin: 15px 0px 0px 350px; 
border-bottom:none; 
padding:12px 12px 8px 12px; 
border-radius:5px 5px 0px 0px; 
width:300px; 
text-align:center;">

<strong style="font-size:18px; color:#000">ABC</strong> 
</div>
<div style="width:968px; 
float:left; 
margin:0px 15px 15px 15px; 
border: solid 1px;
border-color:#CCC; 
border-radius:10px;">
Hello
</div>
```

Can anybody help me to solve this error.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9XFDp/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just nudge the top `div` by `1px` from `top` and use some `background-color` or even `border-bottom` is fine

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9XFDp/)

Added the below properties to the header `div`

```
position: relative;
top: 1px; 
background: #fff; 
z-index: 1;
```

> Note: Don't use `inline` CSS, create classes instead.

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/9XFDp/2/) (Without using `background-color`, used `border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;` instead)

Answer (score 0):

Like this

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y44yu/2/)**

**CSS**

```
.title{
border:solid 1px #CCC; 
margin: 15px 0px 0px 350px; 
border-bottom:1px solid #ffffff; 
padding:12px 12px 8px 12px; 
border-radius:5px 5px 0px 0px; 
width:300px; 
text-align:center;
    font-size:18px; color:#000
        font-weight:bold;
position:relative;
    top:1px;    
}
.content{
    width:968px; 
float:left; 
margin:0px 15px 15px 15px; 
border: solid 1px;
border-color:#CCC; 
border-radius:10px;
}
```